# Python displaying contents of file on browser using Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a Python project using Flask which has the following directory structure -

```
MyProject
|
+-- app
    |
    +-- init.py
    +-- views.py
    +-- downloads
        |
        +-- myFile.txt
    +-- static
        |
        +-- css
            |
            +-- style.css
        +-- img
            |
            +-- flask.jpg
        +-- js
            |
            +-- app.js
    +-- templates
        |
        +-- index.html  
+-- run.py
```

I would like to display the contents of `downloads/myFile.txt` on the web browser. How can it be done?

When I manually tried executing the url `http://<ip>:<port>/static/css/style.css`, the browser displays the contents of the css file (*also the js file*).

But when I try to execute the url `http://<ip>:<port>/downloads/myFile.txt`, it says `Not Found`.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the `style.css` file correctly because it is contained in the [static folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/static/), which is managed by default by flask to return static files, like in your case a style sheet.

In the case of the second link, `Not Found` is returned since that path is not managed by the routes of your application.
To handle it you should do something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
from os.path import join as join_path
from magic import Magic
#...

@app.route('/download/<file_name>')
def download_file(file_name):
    #load abs file path from file name (in your case search for the file in your download folder) -> full_file_path
    full_file_path = join_path(<your_download_folder>, file_name)
    #get mime_type of the file -> mime_type
    mime = Magic(mime=True)
    mime_type = mime.from_file(full_file_path)
    return send_file(full_file_path, mime_type)
```

[Magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) is a python library to read the mime type of a file.

Through the `send_file` method of flask it is possible to directly return a file from it's path. Specifying the `mimetype` your browser will know how to interpret the response returned from the server and correctly display the returned file.